# How do I solve "The required anti-forgery cookie \"__RequestVerificationToken\" is not present." when requesting JSON from C#?

Tags: c#, json, cookies

I'm trying to request JSON data from a website with no published API with HttpWebRequest like this

```
        var cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";

        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        using (Stream webpageStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            webpageStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }


        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
```

but it returns

```
{"HasError":true,"ErrorMessage":"The required anti-forgery cookie \"__RequestVerificationToken\" is not present.","IsErrorHandled":false,"NeedsLogin":false,"Data":null}
```

I noticed there's a __RequestVerificationToken cookie when I submit the form with TamperData, but how do I programatically set its contents to be acceptable by the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to load a html page wich uses this API - it will contain `__RequestVerificationToken` field (or header, it depends on the implementation - you can check all this in the javascript of the page which uses API) - you need to grab it. Then you need to make the request in the question passing saved token along.